# Numpy will load in Jupyter but not in cmd/IDLE

Tags: python, anaconda

I recently installed Anaconda and have some problem loading the numpy. When using Jupyter, there is no error. But I am trying to figure out how to make it also work with IDLE or when running a script through the command prompt, which will now give the this error:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

It is similar when I save a .py file with the import numpy and run through cmd.

Since it works when I use Jupyter (and in fact also Visual Studio Code) I wonder any set up is wrong. To be certain, I am using the IDLE inside the Anaconda folder and also specifically using the python.exe there when using the command prompt.

I observe that the `sys.path` is different when I use Jupyter vs cmd and some other source suggested that might cause problem. I have tried adding the missing paths when using IDLE but even that will not work:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path = (Paths from Jupter)
>>> import numpy as np
(same error as above)
```

Numpy: 1.16.3
Python: 3.7.3 64-bit

Comment: seems to be issue with Anaconda installer not setting the path properly. try and run Scripts\activate. sometimes installing python seperately, running pip and then anaconda confuses the whole thing.

Comment: @user90957  is numpy is install in your system?

Comment: Thanks MEdwin, finally got them to work by using ```Scripts\activate && xxx.py```. From what you know, is there any way to make the conda environment activated by default whenever python is launched, so that it is not necessary to prepend that ```Scripts\activate``` every time?